# how to convert the CGAffineTransform to CGTransform3D?

Tags: cgaffinetransform

how to convert the CGAffineTransform to CGTransform3D?

I use UIImagePickerController as the Camera Controler.  and i add a 3d layer on the upper of the camera view.

then when i want to add a 3d model to the 3d layer . i muset set the 3d scene campera projection matrix . and model view matrix.

but the UIImagePickerController just have a CGAffineTransform .

Answer (score 50):

Try CATransform3DMakeAffineTransform. From Apple's documentation:

Return a transform with the same effect as affine transform 'm'.

```
CATransform3D CATransform3DMakeAffineTransform (CGAffineTransform m)
```

Available in iOS 2.0 and later. Declared In:

```
CATransform3D.h
```

Comment: Also works on macOS 10.5 or layer :)
Here is the link to the doc: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/1436580-catransform3dmakeaffinetransform